# How to force "remember me" users to login again?

Tags: login, cookies

My question is how to force the users that are auto-logged in because they previously checked "remember me" to log in again?

It may be something with cookies, but is there anything I can change/modify to do this ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Generally, using jQuery cookie plugin, the code that checks for a cookie in user's system looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!$.cookie('name-of-cookie')){
    $.cookie('name-of-cookie', 'true', { expires: 2});
.
.
}
```

Is there any similar in Wordpress to handle this?

Comment: You can still do this, using jQuery, since jQuery is bundled with WordPress. the $.cookie() method is not available out of the box with jQuery however, so you'll need to use the $.cookie plugin if you don't want to roll your own handler: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/issues/jjquery.cookie-modified.js_.txt How-To: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the security keys, forcing all cookies to expire and all users to log back in. Edit wp-config.php and change even one character in any of the security strings.

There's a plugin that allows you to set the expiry time on your user's cookies. I haven't personally used it, so proceed with caution: [Cookie Timout](http://www.freemoby.com/2005/05/21/wordpress-plugin-cookie-timeout/)

Sending the user back to `/wp-login.php?reauth=true` removes the cookie and logs the user out, even if he was previously logged in with a cookie.

Finally, if you're developing a plugin or theme, you can call `wp_clear_auth_cookie();` and the currently-logged-in user's cookie will be cleared. This will not necessarily log the user out, but it will remove the cookie for the next time the user visits the site.

Comment: Thank you. Which one of those keys? Anyone ? `define('AUTH_KEY', '');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', '');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', '');
define('NONCE_KEY', '');`

Comment: Any one, but the one that makes most sense in this case would be LOGGED_IN_KEY

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a plugin this one will fix you up:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inactivity-auto-sign-out-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for this. I am looking something more like my updated question. However I will try it if nothing found but I think is not what I want.

Comment: Your updated question is how the suggested pugin handles the issue. There's always at least two ways to do something the wrong way and the right way. All plugin=-s mentioned so far limit the cookie expiration time which will do what you are needing. My suggestion doesn't offer a fancy interface and to make changes to the amount of time logged in you need to actually crack open the code. I just thought I'd give the plugin author some credit instead of copy/pasting his code. Whichever route you choose I'm sure it will work, good luck.